# I need to write in Times New Roman (using TexStudio, my OS is EndeavourOS (Arch based))

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontspec, texstudio, linux

As the topics says I have to write my thesis in Times New Roman on my machine. It uses EndeavourOS, and I am compiling the LaTeX code using Texstudio.

1. Can anyone offer me instructions on how to check if the font is installed on my Computer ? (I installed the ttf-croscore package which contains it, but I'm not sure.)
2. How do I use the "exact" Times New Roman font. (either using Pdflatex or something else)
   This is what my preamble looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\graphicspath{{/home/agnelo/Documents/BUT\ Machine\ HAMK\ Template\ version/images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

I get an error that "Times New Roman" cannot be found.

PS: This is my first time posting, so I apologize for any errors.

Comment: What error? // you need XeLaTeX or Lua TeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @user202729 I get an error that "Times New Roman" cannot be found.

Comment: in that case you can not be using pdftex (as you have tagged the question) you must be using luatex or xetex. (in which case you should not use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`  simplest is to use a Times Roman clone that comes with texlive, such as `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have to use the "exact" Times New Roman if possible. My uni uses a text to speech program that needs the exact times new roman font.

Comment: honestly it seems extremely weird, almost impossible  that it depends on a specific proprietary font (whatever the documentation says) but if you do, then just delete inputenc and use lualatex or xelatex as you are currently doing (not pdflatex as you said you used) and install Times New Roman into your linux system fonts. It is a distributed with Microsoft Windows but available from linux package managers with package name usually something like `mscorefonts`

Comment: This is ubuntu but the basic installation idea is the same https://itsfoss.com/install-microsoft-fonts-ubuntu/

Comment: Your code works fine for me by using `XeLaTeX`, if you suffer still with the same error, and keep the `Times New Roman` font family in a separate folder and use as `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Path = ../Fonts/TimesNewRoman/ ,
UprightFont= TimesNewRoman.otf ,
BoldFont=TimesNewRoman-Bold.otf ,
ItalicFont=TimesNewRoman-Italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=TimesNewRoman-BoldItalic.otf
]{TimesNewRoman}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi but the OP probably needs to obtain the font first, it will work on Windows by default.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you I got it to work by getting the font from the AUR and compiling it using XeLatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suspect there is or was an element of OCR, combined with garbled instructions (e.g. a system that couldn't handle sans serif fonts very well because of poor character differentiation).  While we're lucky in the UK not to suffer too badly from such arbitrary requirements on theses, I had to push quite hard to get them to upload my PDF to the British Library rather than use a scanned and (very well) OCRed version - but some figures hadn't printed brilliantly and scanned worse.

Comment: @ChrisH that was my guess that "Times New Roman" meant "Not Helvetica", more or less.:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wonder if anyone would even notice if the OP submitted in a mix of Latin Modern, Garamond, and Palatino.  But OCR is of course harder for technical text than when a dictionary can be used to help (I read Lord of the Rings with *ores* instead of *orcs*, so mainstream writing isn't immune).  To a Windows user in an administrative context a few years ago there were only 2--3 fonts: TNR, Arial, and maybe Courier New.  A really smart user might acknowledge Wingdings and Symbol to be fonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will work as written with lualatex or xelatex but you should delete `inputenc` which does nothing but warn that it should not be used with those engines.

Times New Roman is a standard Windows font but distributed under a licence that allows it to be installed on other platforms. Most Linux package managers will install it as part of the Microsoft Core Fonts package (`mscorefonts` or similar name, depending on your linux package manager details)